# Sed don't work with a special variable

Tags: json, file, sed

I have a command that adds to a specific location of the file.

```
a="hellotesting"
sed "/^[[:blank:]]*\"testing_$2\": \[$/,/^[[:blank:]]*],*$/ {s/^[[:blank:]]*}$/&`echo $a`/}" $1
```

It's work ! Output (is a JSON file and i don't want to use jq)

```
{
  "mytable_test": [
    {
      "test1": "abc",
      "test2": "def",
      "test2": "ghi"
    }hellotesting
  ],
  "mytable": [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ]
}
```

But I can't put the contents of a file.
My file:

```
yeah
is
test
my
script
```

And in my program:

```
IFS=
a=$(cat file)
sed "/^[[:blank:]]*\"data_$2\": \[$/,/^[[:blank:]]*],*$/ {s/^[[:blank:]]*}$/&`echo $a`/}" $1
```

I have an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 73: unterminated `s' command
```

I want this output:

```
    {
      "mytable_test": [
        {
          "test1": "abc",
          "test2": "def",
          "test2": "ghi"
        }yeah
is
test
my
script
      ],
      "mytable": [
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3"
      ]
    }
```

But, if my file is just:

```
yeah
```

And I cat file in my variable, that work ..
I don't understand ..

Comment: Post the input, what you're trying to achieve and expected output.

Comment: @sjsam I add output :D

Comment: You're expected output is not even valid json . What are you trying to achieve here? :/ Or is it just experiment?

Comment: Experience ! I don't want valid JSON for the moment ;)

Comment: And what are `$1` and `$2` here. Your question looks half baked here :/ You should clearly convey what you're trying to do.

Comment: I see 2 separate outputs in your question but I don't see any input - add that. or is `My file` the input file? If so explain the mapping from that to your output as it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why you would like to corrupt a valid json, but this what you can do

```
$ var="yeah\nis\ntest\nmy\nscript"
$ echo "{                         
  "mytable_test": [
    {
      "test1": "abc",
      "test2": "def",
      "test2": "ghi"
    }hellotesting
  ],
  "mytable": [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ]
}" | sed -E "s/hellotesting$/${var}/"
```

**Output**

```
{
  mytable_test: [
    {
      test1: abc,
      test2: def,
      test2: ghi
    }yeah
is
test
my
script
  ],
  mytable: [
    test1,
    test2,
    test3
  ]
}
```